# Where do you keep your client source and how do you build it into your application?

Tags: go

Consider the backend-for-frontend pattern. You're using an SPA client like Angular or React which requires a build process and the client depends on your server for content/authentication.
How do you do it?
Is my current folder structure suitable?

```
go.mod
/bin
    # output builds into here here
/httpd
    main.go
    /handlers
        index_get.go
        ping_any.go
/platform
    # misc packages go here
```

Comment: This structure works, but what's best is opinion based.

Comment: Yeah that's true. Where do you keep the client source and built client files? How do you access them from both dev and the prod binary?

My makefile contains make dev and make build - perhaps you always build the client into /bin/client but based on an environment variable point the server to serve different folders?